# Que signifie "en rémission" ?

Tags: sens, expressions, usage, santé-et-médecine

J'ai lu le titre d'un article qui dit :

> Une française de 18 ans porteuse du VIH depuis sa naissance **en rémission**.

Mon dictionnaire franco-allemand me donne les traductions incompréhensibles : *Vergebung* qui signifie *pardon* ou *rémittence*.

Le dictionnaire ne connaît pas l'expression *en rémission*.

Quelqu'un peut-il m'aider à comprendre le mot et cette expression dans ce cas et quelles sont leurs utilisations en général?

Comment: La [réponse de Kareen](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14461/7224) me semble très bonne. Le mot allemand est [_Remission_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remission_(Medizin)). En anglais, c'est également [_remission_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cure#Remission).

Comment: J'ai lu la traduction en allemand *Remission*, mais je la connaissait pas. Merci

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La rémission est la diminution momentanée d'un mal.

Par exemple, l'expression *être en rémission* est généralement employée lorsque l'on parle de cancer. Il s'agit d'un stade important vers la guérison. Une personne cancéreuse qui n'a plus de symptômes après un certain nombre de traitements est dite en rémission. La rémission peut durer plusieurs années, jusqu'à l'apparition de nouveaux symptômes ou la guérison complète.

Cette expression est utilisée pour d'autres conditions graves, telles le VIH.

Comment: Le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/r%C3%A9mission/68016) donne : *Atténuation ou disparition momentanée des symptômes d'une maladie aiguë ou chronique.*

Answer (score 1):

Rémission signifie "diminution de symptômes d'une maladie", peu importe la maladie en question.
Il est vrai que l'on utilise plus cette expression en parlant de maladies graves.
Source : http://dictionnaire.cordial-enligne.fr/definition/r%C3%A9mission